# Java passing value back as 3 but shows as zero

Tags: java, class, variables, logic, conways-game-of-life

For some reason the 'numAlive' variable shows as 3 but when passed back to numAlivePass it appears as '0' This is for Conways game of life

***Edited as per comments below***

```
public int countLiveNeighbour(int x, int y){

    int numAlive = 0;
    if(x >= 3 && y >= 3 && x < HEIGHT-3 && y < WIDTH-3)
    {

        if(generation[x][y+1] == ALIVE)       {numAlive++;} 
        if(generation[x][y-1] == ALIVE)       {numAlive++;}
        if(generation[x+1][y] == ALIVE)       {numAlive++;}
        if(generation[x+1][y+1] == ALIVE)     {numAlive++;} 
        if(generation[x+1][y-1] == ALIVE)     {numAlive++;}
        if(generation[x-1][y-1] == ALIVE)     {numAlive++;}
        if(generation[x-1][y+1] == ALIVE)     {numAlive++;}
    }
    if(x ==31 && y==16){
        System.out.println("ALIVE INclass: " + numAlive);
    }

    return numAlive;

}
//cell will be alive in next generation if alive cells = 3 or if already alive then 2 or 3

private int aliveCell(int x, int y){
    int numAlivePass = 0;           
    numAlivePass = countLiveNeighbour(x, y);
    if(x ==31 && y==16){
        System.out.println(" NumAlivePass(ed) = " +numAlivePass+ " Live Neighbour Call = " + countLiveNeighbour(x, y));
    }
    int aliveState= 0;
    if(x ==31 && y==16){
        System.out.println(x + " x val 1, " + y + " x val 1, ALIVE 1: " + numAlivePass + " Alive State 1: " + aliveState);
    }
    if (numAlivePass > 3 || numAlivePass < 2){
        aliveState = DEAD;

    }
    if(numAlivePass == 3){
        aliveState = ALIVE;
        System.out.println("Alive");
    }
    if (generation[x][y] == ALIVE && numAlivePass == 2){
        aliveState = ALIVE;
        System.out.println("Alive");
    }

    return aliveState;
}
```

This is all the code in this class inclusive of the code above:
    package game_of_life;

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class CellularAnimation implements Animatable{


public static final int ALIVE = -1;
public static final int DEAD = 0;
public static final int HEIGHT = 100;
public static final int WIDTH = 100;
public static final int CELL_SIZE = 5;

int generation[][] = new int[HEIGHT][WIDTH];
int nextGeneration[][] = new int[HEIGHT][WIDTH];


public int getCellStatus(int x, int y) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return generation[x][y];
}

public void populateNextGen(){
    for(int x=0; x<=WIDTH-1; x++){
        for(int y=0; y<=HEIGHT-1; y++){
            nextGeneration[x][y] = aliveCell(x,y);
        }
    }

    for(int x=0; x<=WIDTH-1; x++){
        for(int y=0; y<=HEIGHT-1; y++){
            generation[x][y] = nextGeneration[x][y];
        }
    }


}
public void initialise(){
    for(int i = 0;i<HEIGHT-1;i++){
        for(int z = 0;z<WIDTH-1;z++){
            generation[z][i]= DEAD;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("test1");
    generation[30][15]= ALIVE;
    generation[30][16]= ALIVE;
    generation[30][17]= ALIVE;



}
public int countLiveNeighbour(int x, int y){

    int numAlive = 0;
    if(x >= 3 && y >= 3 && x < HEIGHT-3 && y < WIDTH-3)
    {

        if(generation[x][y++] == ALIVE)       {numAlive++;} 
        if(generation[x][y--] == ALIVE)       {numAlive++;}
        if(generation[x++][y] == ALIVE)       {numAlive++;}
        if(generation[x++][y++] == ALIVE)     {numAlive++;} 
        if(generation[x++][y--] == ALIVE)     {numAlive++;}
        if(generation[x--][y--] == ALIVE)     {numAlive++;}
        if(generation[x--][y++] == ALIVE)     {numAlive++;}
    }
    if(x ==31 && y==16){
        System.out.println("ALIVE INclass: " + numAlive);
    }

    return numAlive;

}
//cell will be alive in next generation if alive cells = 3 or if already alive then 2 or 3

private int aliveCell(int x, int y){
    int numAlivePass = 0;           
    numAlivePass = countLiveNeighbour(x, y);
    if(x ==31 && y==16){
        System.out.println(" NumAlivePass(ed) = " +numAlivePass+ " Live Neighbour Call = " + countLiveNeighbour(x, y));
    }
    int aliveState= 0;
    if(x ==31 && y==16){
        System.out.println(x + " x val 1, " + y + " x val 1, ALIVE 1: " + numAlivePass + " Alive State 1: " + aliveState);
    }
    if (numAlivePass > 3 || numAlivePass < 2){
        aliveState = DEAD;

    }
    if(numAlivePass == 3){
        aliveState = ALIVE;
        System.out.println("Alive");
    }
    if (generation[x][y] == ALIVE && numAlivePass == 2){
        aliveState = ALIVE;
        System.out.println("Alive");
    }

    return aliveState;
}


@Override
public void step() {
    populateNextGen();
    //paint(null);
    //implement paint ect here


}
@Override
public void paint(Graphics pGraphics) {
    //super.paint(pGraphics);

    for(int i = 0; i<HEIGHT; i++){
        for(int z = 0; z<WIDTH; z++){
            if(generation[z][i] == ALIVE){
                pGraphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                System.out.println("test");
            }
            else{
                pGraphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            }


            pGraphics.fillRect(z*CELL_SIZE,i*CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE);
        }
    }

}
@Override
public int getWidth() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return WIDTH*CELL_SIZE;
}
@Override
public int getHeight() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return HEIGHT*CELL_SIZE;
}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure of that? Have you printed values before returning and after the call?

Comment: This is a very dangerous construct: `if(generation[x][y++] == ALIVE)`. Always increment separate from use: `y++;  if (generation[x][y] ==...`. In your code the increment occurs *after* you check if alive which is not what you want to do.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels My guess is that OP meant `y+1`, not `y++` (not knowing there's a difference). Either that or OP tried to write some mind-bogglingly confusing code.

Comment: @Christian yes i did it before and after
HovercraftFullOfEels i know y++ is y+1 i have always done that way
Thanks for quick responses

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm with Dukeling on this one.  This is a famous exercise, and all the `x++`, `y++`, `x--` and `y--` expressions should be `x+1`, `y+1`, `x-1` and `y-1` respectively.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels ALIVE is a static variable set as -1 at the top

Comment: @DavidWallace: I see what you two mean, thanks. I think though that we all agree that how he's doing it currently is blatantly wrong.

Comment: How are you actually running this, when your `main` is empty?

Comment: ok i have fixed the y++ and x-- ect, this should not have caused an issue should it have? this main im not using, its running from a different class this is just an object
@DavidWallace

Comment: It's *impossible* for the value passed to the caller of a function to be different from the value you returned (unless you have some severe memory problems with your computer). I suggest you construct an [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example)](http://sscce.org) so we can run the program and see the results for ourselves. But in the process of constructing it, you're likely to figure out the problem yourself.

Comment: Which methods of the `CellularAnimation` class is that other class actually calling?  is it `initialise` then `step` - or something different?

Comment: @Dukeling
This is the outupt from the above code(Just taken one part of it):
ALIVE INclass: 3;         
 NumAlivePass(ed) = 0 Live Neighbour Call = 0;             
31 x val 1, 16 x val 1, ALIVE 1: 0 Alive State 1: 0

Comment: @DavidWallace yes that's how it is doing it, initialize is in the other class.
is there a simplier way of doing any of this that i havent realised, also the x++ gave me a different response to x+1... does this mean the computer is messed up? im on a uni computer

Comment: You've shown a method in `CellularAnimation` called `initialise()`.  Do you have another one somewhere else?  Or is your actual code different from what you've posted?  About the `x++` vs `x+1` thing - the former changes `x` so I would expect it to give you the wrong result.

Comment: @DavidWallace I posted it on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/aJHQdR2f
it has all the code i have not pasted here, the big gaps mean different classes
Also thanks so much for looking at this for me

Comment: That looks like the code for something completely different.  I think you've provided the wrong link.  What I suggest you do is edit THIS question; put all the relevant code HERE.  Make it clear what's in each class.  Don't leave anything out.  And DON'T make people go off and look at other pages.  Because right now, it's not clear what's part of your program and what isn't; and which class calls methods in which other class.  It's too hard trying to look at three different things at once.  Code in ONE PLACE please.